# Redux is Async or Sync

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, synchronization

Search many forum but still confuse, redux is async or sync??
Realize this is a basic question but I had no luck finding the answer elsewhere.
if any one know describe with examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Redux store only supports synchronous data flow ([ref](https://redux.js.org/basics/dataflow)).

This is what you get by default with **createStore()**.

> **Asynchronous** middleware like **redux-thunk** or **redux-promise** wraps the store's **dispatch()** method and allows you to dispatch something
>   other than actions, for example, functions or Promises. Any middleware
>   you use can then interpret anything you dispatch, and in turn, can
>   pass actions to the next middleware in the chain.

For example,

> a Promise middleware can intercept Promises and dispatch a pair of
>   begin/end actions asynchronously in response to each Promise.

[Read More>>](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncflow)

Answer (score 0):

Dispatching actions is synchronous in Redux.

> Without middleware, Redux store only supports synchronous data flow. This is what you get by default with `createStore()`.

For asynchronous actions, you can use `applyMiddleware()`, for middlewares such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).